# Human verification removed code formatting

Tags: bug, status-completed, captcha

On a recent post of mine I included a code block that was formatted correctly in the preview, but was rendered as regular text after I had to go through the human verification screen. Can this be fixed?

Here's the post where I saw it: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/2950682/revisions

It's been modified since then to add the formatting back in.

Comment: Did you type the captcha words correctly the first time, or did it give you a new set of words? I thought I might have had an issue one time when I failed the test.

Comment: No, I typed them in correctly the first time.

Answer (score 6):

Testing this bug.

### Code snippet with tab (\t) character

Trucks
  Compacts
  SUVs
 
 
 
  Ford
  Toyota
  Honda

### Code snippet with 4 spaces

```
<input type="hidden" name="parameters[0].Key" value="Category" />
<select name="parameters[0].Value">
    <option value="Trucks">Trucks</option>
    <option value="Compacts">Compacts</option>
    <option value="SUVs">SUVs</option>
</select>
<input type="hidden" name="parameters[1].Key" value="Manufacturer" />
<select name="parameters[1].Value">
    <option value="Ford">Ford</option>
    <option value="Toyota">Toyota</option>
    <option value="Honda">Honda</option>
</select>
```

Comment: It would seem the bug is limited to only tab characters preceding code blocks, not 4 spaces. The post above was correctly formatted initially, but after two edits and a human verification form it now looks like that.

Answer (score 6):

Thanks to [Nathan's repro steps](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52147/human-verification-removed-code-formatting/57093#57093), we were able to find the issue. This will be fixed in the next build.

Edit: We have rolled back this fix, since it may be causing some other issues, so we have to investigate a little further.

Edit 2: After a few changes, we have reenabled this a few days ago and not seen any issues since. So – all good now; this is fixed.

On a personal note, let me add that

## tabs are evil.

<sub>*runs*</sub>

Comment: Okay, you *want* us to vote for that statement on tabs, right?

Comment: Tabs are not evil. It's the mix of tabs and spaces that is evil. I can't stand spaces, myself.

Comment: If the world would use [elastic tabstops](http://nickgravgaard.com/elastictabstops/), then it would be a better place. Lacking this, for the past decade, I've advocated 1TBS and tabs-then-spaces for other content after the first non-tab character.

Comment: As much as I've always detested aligned variables and comments (and hence never had a need for *inline* tabs, but still love tabs at the start of a line), that elastic tabstops demo is great, @zanlock!

Comment: (He, my comment upvote went to the wrong comment, which I did not even see previously!)

Comment: @Arjan: Huh? I only see one comment upvote, and the only comment before that is yours -- so you must have seen it, if you clicked upvote on anything?

Comment: I really think I upvoted a comment about the elastic tabs. Maybe @zanlok moved that text the the 3rd comment? Anyway, I doubt it's a bug: it's either caused by editing, or I'm simply imagining things — just like *you* are imagining tabs are evil! ;-)

Comment: Sorry guys. I split the comment up so that the two separate ideas were represented on their own merit. Glad to see someone else has heard of elastic tabstops :)